# How to prevent tiny race condition in a consumer

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition

In my applications, two things happen:

- Various threads produce jobs.
- There is a function (but not 1 constantly running thread) that consumes the jobs. This function is started by the producers, but is locked so that it only runs once.

For example, a job is produced:

```
addJobToDatabase(...);
triggerPass();
```

And this is how the consumer function is started:

```
public void triggerPass() {

    // prevent running more than once
    if (onceLock.tryLock()) { // onceLock is a ReentrantLock
        try {

            while (haveJobs()) {
                doJobs();
            }

        } finally {
            onceLock.unlock();
        }
    } else {
        log.info("Pass triggered, but already running");
    }

}
```

Now, there is a tiny race condition possible here. If

- Thread A has left the `while` but not yet done `onceLock.unlock()`
- Thread B does `onceLock.tryLock()` which returns false

...thread B's job is not executed until a later call to triggerPass();

While I doubt it will get me into trouble in practice, can this little gap be closed for correctness?

Comment: I'd wonder why you aren't using the BlockingQueue for producer/consumer.  I'll bet this is old code that you don't want to give up.

Comment: @duffymo In fact I wrote it today :P. The queue is in the database, because it needs to survive crashes and other errors. This is because the jobs are payments that need fulfillment.

Comment: What's wrong with being blocked on trying to obtain a lock and then if `haveJobs()` returned `false` immediately return from the method?

Comment: @BorisPavlović Hmm, that would certainly fix this particular problem, but it might cause a lot of threads waiting for that lock, then doing nothing (if many jobs are produced during 1 pass of handling them).

Comment: You can certainly queue up jobs in the database, but I'd use BlockingQueue in the Java code to manage the producer/consumer interaction.  I'd have far more faith in that data structure than any code I'd write: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ProducerandconsumerbasedonBlockingQueue.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked around it by replacing `tryLock()` with `tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`. It's not nice though, and not even foolproof  if the delay between `there are no more jobs` and `unlock()` is longer than 1 second (and who knows what happens in the database).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately race condition is unavoidable in this design. Want it to be correct? Why don't you just create something like iterator or queue where the read-modify-write action is the single atomic operation?

```
public void triggerPass() {
    Job job = null; 
    while ((job = jobIterator.next()) != null) {
        doJob(job);
    }
}
```